# NSPredicate for selection with the given object in the middle

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, nspredicate

I need to get objects from CoreData, and I am provided with object's timestamp (which is object's property of type `Date`). The thing is, the object I have has to be in the center of this selection.

For example: we have 100 objects in CoreData. I have a timestamp of 45th object. I need to select 30 objects from CoreData and the 45th object should be in the center of this selection. So I need to get objects from 30th to 61s.

I came up with this variant:

`let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "timestamp > %@ AND timestamp < %@", argumentArray: [baseTimestamp, baseTimestamp])`

But, obviously, this won't work.

Is there any chance of getting objects by their `rownum` how we do in SQL? Or any other ways to achieve this selection?

Comment: I guess there are quite a few ways to achieve this. One that comes in mind is to do 2 fetches, one for `n` objects with date before (and equal to) the given date and one for `n` after and concat them. Another approach could be to fetch all the dates sorted (there are apis that you could perform a query but fetch only specific properties) and manually select the slice with the given date in the middle, so you'll have all the objectIDs that your selection needs. I hope that this makes sense.

Comment: I was thinking about 2 fetches, but I’m confused with the performance of this approach...

Comment: I guess you could profile it and see. In case performance is an issue you could go ahead and optimise.

Comment: @Alladinian, will try! Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually, I ended up with 2 separate fetches, since there's no way to achieve this selection with NSPredicate :( (feel free to leave your own answer if I'm wrong, I'll gladly mark it as a right one)